# Angularjs: Disable selected item after selection is made

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is what I have been dealing with for some time now.

For now don't worry about what a plate , orientation or slot is.
I will try to explain the main problem here.

[image]

When a container is selected, a call is made to the API to fetch all the slots of that particular container. An array is returned with all the `slots`

To add another field I use this simple code

```
            $scope.fields = [{
            plate_id: "",
            orientation_id: "",
            slot_id: "",
        }];

          /**
         * Add fields by clicking on the plus button
         */
        $scope.addFormField = function() {
            var newItemNo = $scope.fields.length + 1;
            $scope.fields.push({
                plate_id: "",
                orientation_id: "",
                slot_id: "" + newItemNo
            });
        };
```

To delete a row I use this one.

```
    /**
     * Remove fields by clikcing the trash button
     * @return fields - scope
     */
    $scope.removeFormField = function() {
        var lastItem = $scope.fields.length - 1;
        $scope.fields.splice(lastItem);
    };
```

This works just fine. I ng-repeat the fields in html just like this.

```
    <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group form-group-lg" ng-repeat="form in fields" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loadingForm.plate.$invalid, 'has-success': plate }">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Add Plates</label>

                    <!-- PLATE -->
                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <ui-select ng-model="form.plate_id" name="plate" ng-disabled="!$select.search.length && !$select.items.length" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="true">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="{{$select.disabled ? 'No items available' :'Plate'}}">{{$select.selected.serial_number}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="item.id as item in plates | filter: $select.search">
                                <div ng-bind-html="item.serial_number"></div>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
                    </div>

                    <!-- ORIENTATION -->
                    <div class="col-sm-3" ng-controller="OrientationsCtrl" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loadingForm.orientation.$invalid }">
                        <ui-select ng-model="form.orientation_id" name="orientation" ng-disabled="!$select.search.length && !$select.items.length" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="true">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="{{$select.disabled ? 'No items available' :'orientation'}}">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="item.id as item in allItems | filter: $select.search">
                                <div ng-bind-html="item.name | highlight: $select.search"></div>
                                <small ng-bind-html="item.description | highlight: $select.search"></small>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
                    </div>


              <div class="col-xs-1" ng-class="{ 'has-error': loadingForm.slot.$invalid }">
                        <ui-select ng-model="form.slot_id" name="slot" ng-disabled=" ! $select.search.length && !$select.items.length" theme="bootstrap" ng-required="true">
                            <ui-select-match placeholder="{{$select.disabled ? 'No slots' :'slot'}}">{{$select.selected.slot.slot}}</ui-select-match>
                            <ui-select-choices repeat="item in freeSlots | filter: {selected: false}">
                                <div ng-bind-html="item.slot.slot"></div>
                            </ui-select-choices>
                        </ui-select>
                    </div>
                    <button ng-click="removeFormField()" ng-show="$first -1 " class="btn btn-lg btn-danger">
                        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
```

.. and it just works.

**The problem.**

What I am trying to achieve here is when a user selects a slot lets say slot 1  in this case. When another row is added I want to disable the previously selected slot (which is the 1) and show only the slots which are available for selection (2,3,4..etc)

I have been digging through and found couple of examples such as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27537584/disabled-selected-item-in-angular-for-other-select-option-fields-of-the-same-ite) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790388/angularjs-remove-add-select-box-option-if-other-selection-changes)  but I am just not sure how to apply those methods into mine.

I also added a `selected` key to the `slots` array, just like this.

```
                        angular.forEach(slots, function (slot) {
                      $scope.masterListOfSlots.push({
                          slot: slot,
                          selected: false,
                      });
                    });
```

And filtered it in the html, but wasn't sure again.

**Note**: The user must be able to deselect and select between slots.

Would someone show me a proper way to solve this. Thanks!